# Programmatically set wake on time

Tags: c#, c++, windows-7-embedded

We are creating a display system which we will be running on top of Windows 7 embedded.
The computers will not have keyboard or mouse, thus will have no direct user interaction.

Since these computers will only be used during certain times we would like to define schedules for them and make them power off (including their screens), and automatically power on again at specific times.

For this, we need to be able to set the bios WakeOnRTC timer from code. It is not sufficient to wake from hibernate or sleep, as referred to at [Schedule machine to wake up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141735/schedule-machine-to-wake-up).

I know from others that MythBuntu can do this, but that is Linux-based.
I've also heard this is easier to achieve with UEFI-bioses that are emerging.

At this point we are open to select any bios if anyone has a solution.

Comment: I won't put this as an answer as i only skimmed through this some years ago. I also wanted to get WOT but as i found out it is BIOS specific which means you have to know where the BIOS stores this information and then set it from your OS. Setting this from your OS is only possible with administrative rights. Some BIOS were designed in a way that it was only possible to do this in real-mode which once the OS has left there is no way of going back (nowadays). Search for UEFI information on this. It is supposed to be way easier to interact with UEFI from the OS then with the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to put too much because this question has already been answered, see the following links.

[C#: How to wake up system which has been shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061844/c-how-to-wake-up-system-which-has-been-shutdown)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49798/Wake-the-PC-from-standby-or-hibernation

In short the solution revolves around the following two Win32 API functions:

[CreateWaitableTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492(v=vs.85).aspx)

[SetWaitableTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289(v=vs.85).aspx)