# Waking up a machine from sleep after an interval in .NET

Tags: c#, timer, sleep, wakeup

My requirement is that I want the system to wake up automatically after an interval.I followed a few articles and also saw some stackoverflow posts regarding this issue. I've noticed that on Sleep, all the timers and events are shut. The articles/posts I followed are:

[Schedule machine to wake up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141735/schedule-machine-to-wake-up?rq=1)

[C#: How to wake up system which has been shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061844/c-how-to-wake-up-system-which-has-been-shutdown)

[Wake up from Sleep (CreateWaitableTimer) in C#](http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/wake-up-from-sleep-createwaitabletimer-in-csharp/)

All of the articles have the waitable timer concept in common which I feel is the only way to achieve wake up from sleep. The problem is that it does not work for me. I have tried the code on a windows 8 machine and tablet. I also tried enabling the option of Allow Wake up timers in the control panel. I only found this option in the windows 8 desktop but it wasn't present in tablet. I read in one more post that the system should support wake up also in order for it to work. Is there any working solution to this problem or is it a limitation I have to bear with?

Comment: can you post some code...

Comment: Hi vikky, The code is present in the 3 attached links. Its the same thing

Comment: would it be possible to keep CPU on even on sleep so that timers continue their work?

Comment: Yes,timer should work even the CPU is in sleep mode...

Comment: but it doesnt. :( Whereas in android there is a concept of alarms. Task scheduling would complicate things isn't it? I wasn't clear about the timer interval and I dint create a timerproc in setwaitable timer. How do I test the timer to work on sleep? should I power on monitor after timer elapse?a normal timer would not work right?

Comment: Yeah its complex situation :P Look at that URL :- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49798/Wake-the-PC-from-standby-or-hibernation and download the exe and chek it works or not....even check in other PC(if possible)...although I think it is the same code which you are using...